# R scrape value prices to data frame

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape only the buy and sell price of this website

https://www.gs.de/en/products/leverage/long-short-knock-outs/dax/DE000UH85DS5

to a data.frame.

I tried

```
gs<-"https://www.gs.de/en/products/leverage/long-short-knock-outs/dax/DE000UH85DS5"
gs.read<-read_html(gs)
rank <- gs.read %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes('body') %>% 
  xml2::xml_find_all("//div[contains(@class, 'value')]") %>% 
  rvest::html_text()
```

But I can't seem to locate the values.

Comment: The link does not appear to be available to those of us inside the US and changing `*.de` to `*.com` does not help.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I don't know how I can help you with this

Comment: page uses websocket